# Creating C++ templates inside function with C linkage

Tags: c++

Consider a shared library `myLib` written in `C++11` and an executable `myExe` written in `C++17` that calls functions in `myLib`. However, `myExe` is compiled by a different compiler and so the two are linked together using C linkage, and the header for `myLib` takes care of that. Once inside the `myLib`, I would like to use templates to enjoy the privileges of `C++` as early as possible in the code. Is there a way to go about doing this that would avoid littering the global namespace with seperate functions for all supported types? I have control over the source code for both.

For example, inside `myLib`, I would like to avoid:

```
// Exported function for int
void myCLinkedFuncForInt(int A)
{
    // templated C++ internal function for myLib
    myLib::myFunc(A);
}

// Exported function for float
void myCLinkedFuncForFloat(float A)
{
    // templated C++ internal function for myLib
    myLib::myFunc(A);
}
```

where I define `myLib::myFunc` as a template.

Some fun, yet unsafe things I have tried:

```
void myCLinkedFuncForEverything(void* A, const char* type)
{
    const std::string CppType(type);

    if (CppType == "int")
        return myLib::myFunc(*(reinterpret_cast<int*>(A));
    if (CppType == "float")
        return myLib::myFunc(*(reinterpret_cast<float*>(A));

    // If we reached here, we are unsupported
    std::cout << "Data type not supported" << std::endl;
}
```

Then in `myExe`, I cast everything to a `void*` and supply `type`. What other options do I have for `C++11`?

**Note:** `std::variant` and `std::any` came in `C++17`.

Comment: That second variant is pretty unsafe, consider typos in the string passed! Much better is an enum, apart from not being able to introduce typos comparison is much more efficient as well (consider a switch-statement then). Still user can select bad enum value for the value passed, so some issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to go about doing this that would avoid littering the global namespace with seperate functions for all supported types?

No, as what you want to do is to instantiate the template for each such type, and make it available from C, you'll have to define it for every type.